# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when the package is changed from hello to foo.

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I can get the spring boot example program working successfully when I follow the instructions available at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/.

If I add HelloService and HelloServiceImpl, code shown below, to hello package and change HelloController.java to call sayHello method, it works as expected and from `http://localhost:8080`, I see the message shown below, as expected.

*Greetings from Spring Boot! helloService = Hello from HelloServiceImpl*

Now, if I move HelloService and HelloServiceImpl to **foo** package, then after compilation when I run it, I get the error shown below.

Why the spring boot/framework is not able to pick up the needed beans from '**foo**' package? I am able to verify it can pick up the bean successfully from **hello** package, though.

Thanks,

***cat HelloService.java***

```
package hello;

public interface HelloService {

    public String sayHello();   

}
```

***cat HelloServiceImpl.java***

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service("helloService")
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.apress.prospring3.springblog.service.HelloService#sayHello()
     */
    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello  from HelloServiceImpl ";
    }

}
```

In HelloController.java, change return statement in the index method as shown below, so that the hello service is invoked.

***cat HelloController.java***

```
package hello;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired 
    private HelloService helloService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot! helloService = " + helloService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

When I run the command shown below, there are no errors.

$ java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar

$ java -version

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

$ which java

/usr/bin/java

$ ls -lt /usr/bin/java

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Mar  9 22:00 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

If I move HelloService.java and HelloServiceImpl.java to **foo** package from **hello** package and no other change, I get the error below when I try to run it. Why it is not able to pick up from '**foo**' package when it can do it successfully from **hello** package? How to fix this issue? Does it mean these two classes must reside in **hello** package only for it to work?

Thx,

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private foo.HelloService hello.HelloController.helloService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No qualifying bean of type [foo.HelloService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    ... 6 more
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private foo.HelloService hello.HelloController.helloService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [foo.HelloService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [foo.HelloService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially when HelloService is in hello package, @ComponentScan on the Configuration class tells Spring to look for other components, configurations, and services in the the hello package, allowing it to find this class.
Now since you have moved HelloService to foo package, @ComponentScan cannot find it any more; you need to specify the new package name as well like:

```
    @ComponentScan({"hello","foo"})
```

Comment: Thanks in Application.java, if I change @ComponentScan to what you have shown, I am able to verify the I can run the application successfully from the command line, with no errors. However, when I go to the URL shown below, I am getting a different error :-(. From localhost:8080, the error is Whitelabel Error Page.
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: There should be a stack trace on the console for you to see what happened. Since this is now a different issue I would suggest a new thread.

Comment: Thanks Dave. There are no errors on the console. After more investigation, I am able to verify spring dependency injection mechanism is able to pick up the classes from another package when basePackageClass is specified in the @ComponentScan annotation statement as shown below.

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { HelloService.class, ApplicationService.class })` . The important take away for me is, I need to keep all the classes related to a component in some package like "hello" and then with minimum lines of coding, spring dependency injection mechanism is able to bring it all together. If I have to cross boundaries between packages, first I need to ask why I am organizing the code like that and if it is absolutely needed then specify basePackageClasses in the @ComponentScan annotation. Thanks, this question can be marked as answered and thanks Prakash and Dave.